# Convert date ( smalldatetime) and hour (tinyint) column into datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime-format

I have two columns (Date column which is smalldatetime and Hour column which is smallint) in one table of SQL server database as shown below

```
ScenarioId  ZoneId  Date    Hour    DemandMW    Hour
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1   2490.6  2018-01-02 00:00:00
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2   2405.8  2018-01-03 00:00:00
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 3   2364    2018-01-04 00:00:00
...
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 4   2358    2018-01-05 00:00:00
```

I like to create another datetime column combining the two as:

```
ScenarioId  ZoneId  Date    Hour    DemandMW    Hour DateTime
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1   2490.6  2018-01-02 00:00:00 2018-01-02 01:00:00
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2   2405.8  2018-01-03 00:00:00 2018-01-02 02:00:00
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 3   2364    2018-01-04 00:00:00 2018-01-02 03:00:00
...
618011031   71400   2018-01-01 00:00:00 24  2358    2018-01-05 00:00:00 2018-01-02 24:00:00
```

How to write the select query. Please advice.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `dateadd()`?

```
select dateadd(hour, [hour], [date]) as [datetime]
```

If you want this as part of the table, then add a computed column:

```
alter table t add [datetime] as (dateadd(hour, [hour], [date]));
```

Note:  `date`, `datetime`, and `hour` are really bad names for columns because these are all SQL Server keywords.